Distinguishing Firestore Snapshot Listener 'REMOVE' Event Reasons in Query
I have a snapshot listener for a query like this:
firestore
    .collection("...")
    .whereEqualTo("available", true)
    .orderBy("sort", Query.Direction.DESCENDING) 
    .limit(10)

The listener trigger "REMOVE" event under the following conditions:

When a user clicks delete in the UI, we update the "available" field to false, triggering a "REMOVE" event.

When the query returns 10 items and the user adds one, the last item gets removed because the newly added item is now at index 0, which also triggers a "REMOVE" event for the last item.


My issue is how to differentiate between the reasons behind the "REMOVE" events? (Knowing that the data attached with the event is the OLD data)
My current solution is to launch a Firestore.get() with docId to fetch the new data and make appropriate changes.
Thank you!

What do you mean by "differentiate between the reasons behind the "REMOVE" events"?

@AlexMamo See point 1 and 2 in the question.

@FrankvanPuffelen I got it, puf.

There is no specific information in the API to distinguish between the two situations: all it tells you is that the document snapshot is no longer part of the query.
If you really need to know whether the document was deleted, reading it is indeed a valid approach. An alternative is to make the limit on the query one higher, so request 11 items but only show 10 of them. That way if document 10 is not removed, it'll still be in the results as number 11 - the user just won't see it.
